# Java: parsing of RIFF containers without resorting to Object and typecasting

Tags: java, binaryfiles, binary-data, riff

I'm writing some code to parse RIFF containers in Java (for educational purposes, I know that there are tons of libraries for Java that load `.wav` or other RIFF files). My design aim is to stick to format as close as possible.

The basic RIFF format is very simple, according to Wikipedia:

> - 4 bytes: an ASCII identifier for this chunk (examples are "fmt " and "data"; note the space in "fmt ").
> - 4 bytes: an unsigned, little-endian 32-bit integer with the length of this chunk (except this field itself and the chunk identifier).
> - variable-sized field: the chunk data itself, of the size given in the previous field.
> - a pad byte, if the chunk's length is not even.

I'm currently struggling with representation of variable-sized fields. So far the best I've came up with looks like that. First is abstract class `BaseFormat`, which is a base for all format-parsing classes:

```
abstract class BaseFormat {
    BaseFormat(MyStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    MyStream stream;
    public MyStream stream() { return stream; }

    abstract public void read() throws IOException;
}
```

It just stores a reference to the stream and acts as an interface with `read` method to be fulfilled. Then there are two main format classes:

```
public class Riff extends BaseFormat {
    public Riff(MyStream stream) {
        super(stream);
    }

    @Override
    public void read() throws IOException {
        chunks = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
        while (!stream.eof()) {
            Chunk c = new Chunk(stream);
            c.read();
            chunks.add(c);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Chunk> chunks;
    public ArrayList<Chunk> chunks() { return chunks; }
}

public class Chunk extends BaseFormat {
    Chunk(MyStream stream) {
        super(stream);
    }

    public void read() throws IOException {
        tag = stream.getAsciiString(4);
        len = stream.getInt();
        MyStream substream = stream.getBytesAsSubstream(len);

        switch (tag) {
            case "FMT1":
                Fmt1Body b1 = new Fmt1Body(stream);
                b1.read();
                body = b1;
                break;
            case "FMT2":
                Fmt2Body b2 = new Fmt2Body(stream);
                b2.read();
                body = b2;
                break;
            // etc, etc, many various subformats
        }

        if (len % 2 == 1)
            stream.skipBytes(1);
    }

    private String tag;
    public String tag() { return tag; }

    private int len;
    public int len() { return len; }

    private Object body;
    public Object body() { return body; }
}
```

Nothing fancy goes on there. For the sake of brevity, I'm not posting `MyStream` class, it's a very simple wrapper over `InputStream` that features useful utility functions like `getInt`, `getByte`, `getAsciiString`, etc.

Every piece of RIFF format gets its own class. Whole RIFF file is `Riff`, which in turn tries to read chunks as `Chunk` class, which in turn read chunk header + body, and then magic happens: a big `switch` inside `Chunk.read()` chooses which format class inside the chunk to apply - i.e. `Fmt1Body`, `Fmt2Body`, etc.

It works and you can actually read RIFF files with it. The problem I'm having is that all different chunk formats are represented by a different classes which have nothing in common. So when working with file parsed in memory, I end up doing lots of type checking and upcasting, i.e. something like:

```
for (Chunk chunk : riff.chunks()) {
    Object cbody = chunk.body();
    if (cbody instanceof Fmt1Body) {
        Fmt1Body body = (Fmt1Body) cbody;
        // do something with FMT1 chunk body using `body`, i.e.
        System.out.println("title = " + body.getTitle());
    } else if (cbody instanceof Fmt2Body) {
        Fmt2Body body = (Fmt2Body) cbody;
        // do something with FMT2 chunk body using `body`, i.e.
        System.out.println(body.getWidth() + "x" + body.getHeight());
    }
}
```

etc, etc. This is normal in many functional languages, but I guess it's a bad way of doing things in Java. Is there a better way to represent RIFF container in memory without resorting to `Object` + type checking + upcasting (or some equivalently useless interface like `BaseFormat` that would need casting anyway)?

#### Sources of subformat classes

For those interested in subformat classes, here are some samples to demonstrate that they have nothing in common beyond using the `stream` and having `read()` method:

```
public class Fmt1Body extends BaseFormat {
    Fmt1Body(MyStream stream) {
        super(stream);
    }

    @Override
    public void read() throws IOException {
        title = stream.getAsciiString(64);
        artist = stream.getAsciiString(64);
        album = stream.getAsciiString(64);
    }

    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String album;

    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public String getArtist() { return artist; }
    public String getAlbum() { return album; }
}

public class Fmt2Body extends BaseFormat {
    Fmt2Body(MyStream stream) {
        super(stream);
    }

    @Override
    public void read() throws IOException {
        width = stream.getInt();
        height = stream.getInt();
        bitmap = stream.getBytes(width * height);
    }

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private byte[] bitmap;

    public int getWidth() { return width; }
    public int getHeight() { return height; }
    public byte[] getBitmap() { return bitmap; }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to give you advice when you don't show the actual code. The `body.read();` won't compile, since `body` is `Object`.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is obviously a really stripped down version of actual code — in real-life, of course, there are several dozens of chunk format classes. The contents of chunk parsers are not that imporant — they can be basically anything. I've fixed it compile.

Comment: Well, it's probably quite possible to create a not useless interface that wouldn't need casting, but it's hard to suggest things when you present things in an overly abstract fashion.

Comment: Ok, hang on, I'll post an example of two subformat classes, you'll see that they have absolutely nothing in common.

Comment: You should also show what the "something" is in `do something with FMT1 chunk body using body`.

Comment: @Kayaman Ok, looks like all done.

Comment: At least one thing I'd do is create a factory method `BaseFormat.read(tag, myStream);` that would create, read and return the proper `FmtBody` instance. Even if all the formats can't share one interface, it may be possible to create a few interfaces that are shared by some of the formats. Or you might not get any advantage. You've basically showed that you have data, but in order to plan a better design one would have to know what you will do with that data. In your examples  you could override `toString()` to achieve the behaviour (printing the info) without using `instanceof`.

Comment: The very idea of these parsers is actually that I want to make it as generic as possible and have no assumptions on how these data should be used.

Comment: And that's exactly what makes it impossible to achieve what you want. Making a "generic system" is generally inefficient, because you want "everything" to be possible, making it impossible to make anything efficient! See also [Inner-platform effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).